# How to scale Konsole background image

Tags: kde, konsole

By default, background image is not scaled, which means a good resolution picture will be extremely zoomed in.
I Remember reading setting this wasn't doable in the UI, but was doable in the config file. I haven't been able to find how.
Anyone knows?

Answer (score 1):

Color schemes configs: *.colorscheme
~/.local/share/konsole/
/usr/share/konsole/

1. You need to create new colorscheme in UI
2. Open file in ~/.local/share/konsole/
3. at the end of file you can find "FillStyle"
4. change the value to the one you want
   example: "FillStyle=Stretch"